# Select elements within target div (row) on event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table from which I need to select all of the values of the row after an event done in the same row (in this case is a `keyup` event) with `jQuery`. The table could have many rows but the selection has to be on the items of the row event.

**This is the HTML of the table:**

```
<table class="table" id="form-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Qty</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Discount</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">Hidden</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row-1">
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td class="description-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="companySelect">
                        {% for product in product_options %}
                        <option>{{ product }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="qty-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty" placeholder="Qty" min="0" step="1">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="price-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" min="0.01" placeholder="Price">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="discount-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="discount" placeholder="0" min="0.01" max="99.99">
                </div>
                <div>%</div>
            </td>
            <td class="amount-column"></td>
            <td class="hidden-column">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="hiddenCheck">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And looks like this on the site:

[image: Table in website]

For more context: I am making a quote app in which I'll type the price and quantity of each item in each row and I need to update the "amount" column after each `keyup`. So I need to know how to select the proper "qty", "price", "discount" and "amount" id's of the row typed to do that.

Comment: `$(this).closest("tr")`?

Comment: You shouldn't repeat IDs in each row. Use classes instead. `$(this).closest("tr").find(".qty")`

Comment: @Barmar the OP is using `id` so we can't find it by class name `<input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty" `

Comment: @MaiPhuong I know, I told him to change to classes.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly,** The `id` attribute is unique, So you should replace it with `class` like this

```
<input type="number" class="form-control qty"  placeholder="Qty" min="0" step="1">
```

**Secondly,** You can get the `tr` by using `.closest()` like this `$(this).closest("tr")`

**Finally,** You can calculate individual row by creating another method named `updateAmount_per_row` like below:

```
function updateAmount_per_row(tr){
  var qTy = getValue_by_className(tr, '.qty-column .qty');
  var price = getValue_by_className(tr, '.price-column .price');
  var amount = qTy * price;
  
  tr.find('.amount-column').html(amount);
}
```

```js
$(".qty-column, .price-column").on("keyup", function(){
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  updateAmount_per_row(tr);
});

function updateAmount_per_row(tr){
  var qTy = getValue_by_className(tr, '.qty-column .qty');
  var price = getValue_by_className(tr, '.price-column .price');
  var amount = qTy * price;
  
  tr.find('.amount-column').html(amount);
}

function getValue_by_className(tr, className){
  var value = parseInt(tr.find(className).val(), 10);
  return value >= 0 ? value : 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="form-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Qty</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Discount</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">Hidden</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row-1">
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td class="description-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" class="companySelect">
                        <option>Product A</option>
                        <option>Product B</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="qty-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control qty"  placeholder="Qty" min="0" step="1">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="price-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control price"  min="0.01" placeholder="Price">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="discount-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" class="discount" placeholder="0" min="0.01" max="99.99">
                </div>
                <div>%</div>
            </td>
            <td class="amount-column"></td>
            <td class="hidden-column">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="hiddenCheck">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-2">
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td class="description-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" class="companySelect">
                        <option>Product A</option>
                        <option>Product B</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="qty-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control qty"  placeholder="Qty" min="0" step="1">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="price-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control price"  min="0.01" placeholder="Price">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="discount-column">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" class="discount" placeholder="0" min="0.01" max="99.99">
                </div>
                <div>%</div>
            </td>
            <td class="amount-column"></td>
            <td class="hidden-column">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="hiddenCheck">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Carlos Gonzalez Does this answer your question? Don't forget to give me an upvote and mark my answer as resolved by clicking the tick to help the reader in the future, bro ^^!

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work this way. I found out after I did `console.log(this)` right after the `keyup` that `this` is referencing the whole document (#document). Because of this nothing else seems to work (finding the closest 'tr' and everything else).

Answer (score 0):

Using [Mai Phuong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12582716/mai-phuong) answer as testing I managed to make it work by using the `target` property instead of `this`, because `this` for some reason was referencing the whole document (`#document`).

Here is the `keyup` event listener:

```
  $('.price, .qty, .discount').keyup((event) => {
    let tr = event.target.closest('tr');
    updateAmount(tr);
  });
```

and here's the final `updateAmount` function:

```
function updateAmount(tr) {
  let qty = $(tr).find('.qty').val();
  let price = $(tr).find('.price').val();
  let discount = $(tr).find('.discount').val();

  let amount = (qty * price * (100 - discount)) / 100;

  $(tr).find('.amount').html(amount);
}
```